# Is there a way to send an HTTP request using Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, http, vercel

I just deployed my React app to Vercel, but it's not being able to send HTTP requests, I'm getting this error:

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

My backend is deployed on ECS with an HTTP endpoint, what could I do to solve this? I already tried to set a meta tag, but it didn't work.

Comment: As the message says... use HTTPS instead of HTTP. This is a pretty standard requirement nowadays.

Comment: I allowed HTTPS on my container but it still doesn't works, do you have any tips on that?

Comment: So is it now using https? Are you getting the same error?

Comment: I had to do some things with a load balancer, it's fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could describe what those are, to help anyone else with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick solution to this, rather than loading your page via http or if you are using Vercel you can never load the page over HTTP. one thing you can do is set the site settings to **ALLOW INSECURE CONTENT** and it will fix the problem temporarily.